# How does social media sites store posts

Tags: mysql, database, facebook

Do social media sites such as Facebook and twitter, store posts in a database? Like mysql? Wouldn't the database be extremely large? Does Facebook or social media sites remove old post?

Comment: This topic appears to off topic here at Superuser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use a huge distributed "database" system like Hadoop. The databases are exteremely huge, I understand Facebook's one is over 2Pb (Petabytes) already. I don't think they remove old posts, but they do move them to older/slower technologies. Keep the latest data fresh and online, preferably in RAM.

The basic idea is to store the data in little bits all over the place, and have intelligent programs that can figure out where the data is when you need it. Also let each bit do its own calculations, so that you never have to have all the data in one place. Something like facebook is perfect for this, because you are usually only dealing with 1 person's data at a time - so it doesnt matter too much if joe's info is in a different server than sam's.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop